# PySpark Count Over Windows Function

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function that is driving me crazy and I am supposed to use only PySpark.

The table below is a representation of the data:

[image: Input]

There are IDs, Name, Surname and Validity over which I can partition by, but I should lit the value of the percentage of emails that are set correctly by ID.

Like the image below:

[image: Expected Output]

How can I solve this problem?

```
window = Window.partitionBy("ID", "email", "name", "surname", "validity").orderBy(col("ID").desc())

df = df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window))

df_new = df.withColumn("total valid emails per ID", df.select("validity").where(df.validity == "valid" & df.row_num == 1)).count()
```

Comment: `should lit the value of the percentage of emails that are set correctly by ID.` What exactly do you mean by `correctly`?

Comment: "There are IDs, Name, Surname and Validity over which I can partition by, but I should lit the value of the percentage of emails that are set correctly by ID." This means only the rows that have under the column Validty the value Valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
win = Window.partitionBy("ID", "email", "name", "surname")

df = df.withColumn(
    "pct_valid",
    F.sum(F.when(F.col("validity") == "Valid", 1).otherwise(0)).over(win)
    / F.col("total emails"),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
df.withColumn("ValidAsNumber", F.when(F.col("Validity") == "Valid", 1).otherwise(0))\
  .withColumn("TotalValid", F.sum("ValidAsNumber").over(Window.partitionBy("ID")))\
  .withColumn("PercentValid", F.expr("(TotalValid/TotalEmails)*100")).show()
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output (I kept the intermediate columns for understanding, you can drop them):

[image: Output]